# How to save the user's authorization in session in react?

Tags: reactjs, session, routes, save

When reloading the web application, the application again directs us to the main page and we need to log in again. below is the code that is written for routing and the code of the application itself.

code from file "AppRout"

```
const AppRouter = () => {

    const {isAuth} = useContext(AuthContext);
    return (
        isAuth
            ?
            <Routes>
                <Route path="*" element={<MainPage/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/catalog" element={<Catalog/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/catalog/:id" element={<Booking/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/account" element={<Account/>}/>
            </Routes>
            :
            <Routes>
                <Route path="*" element={<MainPage/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" element={<LogIn/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/registration" element={<Registration/>}/>
            </Routes>

    );
};
```

code from file "App"

```
function App() {
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{
            isAuth,
            setIsAuth
        }}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <AppRouter/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </AuthContext.Provider>

    );
};
```

please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you do authentication with cookies or JWTs or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use JWT, then you can use local storage to persist if the user is authenticated or not.

For example: after performing an api call

```
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const user = { username, password };
  // send the username and password to the server
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://your-api/api/login",
    user
  );
  // set the state of the user
  setUser(response.data)
  // store the user in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('user', response.data)
  console.log(response.data)
};
```

And you can get the user like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (loggedInUser) {
      const foundUser = JSON.parse(loggedInUser);
      setUser(foundUser);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Is that safe from getting hacked?